# How to delete row using JPA while keeping the database in a consistent state

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to create a database with JPA. My problem is I can't figure it out how to configure the entities so :

- if a project is deleted the employees stays in the database
- if an employee is deleted the project stays in the database if there is at least one employee still working on the project

I have two entities like:

```
@Entity(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Project implements Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="PROJ_EMPL",
            joinColumns=
                @JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="PROJECT_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=
                @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", referencedColumnName="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    )
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

    ...

@Entity(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="employeeList",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Project> projectList;

    ...
```

Comment: Your second condition implies you want the `Project` deleted when `employeeList` is empty?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to do.

Comment: From a gut feeling (and a bit of googling around), I don't think you can do this *and* keep the `@ManyToMany` mapping. Conceptually, `Project` is a standalone entity which means it should preserve the invariant that it has at least one employee assigned to it. Maybe make the `removeEmployee()` method refuse to work if it would clear the `employeeList`. Bottom line: you need additional application code to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I have heard about you can add "remove", "add" , etc. methods but I haven't found any good documentation about them, how I should implement them. Do you know some maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, I don't think you can do this utilizing JPA alone and I argue it shouldn't be possible.

Conceptually, what you specified is a invariant of your `Project`: "Have at least one member in `employeeList`."
I like entities that protect their own invariants, maybe like so:

```
public class Project {
  @ManyToMany
  private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

  private Project(){ } /* we need this for Hibernate */
  public Project(Collection<Employee> initialMembers) {
    employeeList.addAll(initialMembers);
  }

  public boolean removeEmployee(Employee e) {
    if (employeeList.size() <= 1) return false;
    employeeList.remove(e);
    return true;
  }

  public int employeesCnt() {
    return employeeList.size();
  }
}
```

Application logic needs to implement your requirement:

```
public ProjectController {
  private Project instance = /* get your project somehow */;

  @Transactional
  public void reduceEmployeeCnt() {
    if (!instance.removeEmployee()) {
      jpaSession.remove(instance);
    }
  }
}
```

Another way would be a EntityListener `@PreRemove` like described [here](http://www.hascode.com/2013/02/adding-multiple-entitylisteners-to-an-entity-in-jpa-2/).